# Internal Server Error 500 using XMLReader()

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

I encountered a strange problem... I'm using XMLReader() to open large XML file from remote server and parse it.On local server I can open XML file from remote server and successfully parse it. But when trying the same on the real server I getting  this error `Internal Server Error 500.` 
I have tried create temporary file using Curl...

```
     $xml = new XMLReader();

     $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'Temp_XML');

     $fp = fopen($temp_file, 'w+');
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
     curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
     fclose($fp);
     $xml->open($temp_file);
```

But no success, the same error.
Why this happening?
**1.Edited**
`[fastcgi:error] [pid 18996:tid 139642498168576] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56057] FastCGI: comm with (dynamic) server "/usr/local/fastcgi/cgi-bin/php-cgi" aborted: (first read) idle timeout (300 sec)`  this error . I have tried increase time out using function set_time_limit(3600); But seems this does not work.

Comment: That is just an error response from the webserver. Check the PHP error log file on the server for the actual error.

Comment: Why are you using curl here? why don't you try 2 simple lines? `$xml = simplexml_load_file('filename.xml');
var_dump($xml);`

Comment: `simplexml_load_file()` another problem with memory usage for large XML files.

Comment: `[fastcgi:error] [pid 18996:tid 139642498168576] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56057] FastCGI: comm with (dynamic) server "/usr/local/fastcgi/cgi-bin/php-cgi" aborted: (first read) idle timeout (300 sec)` seems this error . I have tried increase time out using function `set_time_limit(3600);` But seems this does not work. What to do?

Comment: Why don't you first run this on the CLI and see what actually happens?

Comment: My problem is solved. I have splitted process. Thank to all for the answers.